# ui.router not working ? here is my app on plunker:http://plnkr.co/edit/JdRB2m0aWjllDcze09S2?p=preview

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am new to angularjs ,i make a sample app and now i  add ui.router to the app and its showing nothing even links are are not working .
i want to submit a form and show all form data on about.html.
**Index.html**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html ng-app="mylinkApp">
     <head>
        <title>Angular app (Task)</title>

      <meta charset="utf-8">

       <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.0/css/font-awesome.css" />
        <link href="css/simple-sidebar.css" rel="stylesheet">
       <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular.js"></script>
       <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.8/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script> 
       <script src="js/script.js"></script>
        <script src="js/homeDataDirective.js"></script>

      </head>

          <!-- ########################################### -->

        <body ng-controller="mainController">
               <div class="wrapper">
                 <header id="header" class="clear">
                <h1><img src="../Code/img/logo.png" style="width:200px" height="100px"/></h1>
            </header>
           </div>

         <div id="wrapper">

            <!-- Sidebar -->
              <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
                  <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                      <li class="sidebar-brand">
                          <a href="">
                              Quick Links
                          </a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                          <a href="#home">Home</a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                          <a href="#about">About</a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                          <a href="#siteMap">SiteMap</a>
                      </li>

                   </ul>
              </div>
      <div id="page-content-wrapper">
                  <div class="container-fluid">
                      <div >
                           <div ng-view class="jumbotron text-center" style="height:475px"></div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>


        </div>

     <div id="wrapper">
         <footer id="footer" class="clear">

        <p style="text-align:center">Copyright &copy; 2015 - All Rights Reserved</p>

       </footer>
    </div>
     </body>
     </html>
```

**script.js**

```
// create the module and name it mylinkApp
```

var mylinkApp= angular.module('mylinkApp',['ui.router']); 
       mylinkApp.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', 
     function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

```
   $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/index.html'); 

  // See route.webapp.js for allowed routes 
 $stateProvider 
    .state('home', { 
             url: '/home', 
            templateUrl: '../templates/home.html', 
            controller: 'homeController' 
          }) 
     .state('about', { 
    url: '/about', 
      templateUrl: '../templates/about.html', 
              controller: 'aboutController' 
            }) 
       .state('siteMap', { 
       url: '/siteMap', 
      templateUrl: '../templates/sitemap.html', 
      controller: 'contactController' 
           }) 

       } 
       ]); 

    // create the controller and inject Angular's $scope 
   mylinkApp.controller('homeController', function($scope) { 
      // create a message to display in our view 
       $scope.message = 'Everyone come and see how good I look!'; 

    }); 

        // create the controller and inject Angular's $scope 
  mylinkApp.controller('mainController', function($scope,$state) { 
   // create a message to display in our view 
     // $scope.message = 'Everyone come and see how good I look!'; 
     $state.go('home'); 
          }); 

     mylinkApp.controller('aboutController', ['$scope', 'userService', function($scope, userService) { 
       $scope.userService = userService;
       $scope.user = $scope.userService.user; 
       $scope.message = 'Look! I am an about page.'; 
   }]); 

      mylinkApp.controller('contactController', function($scope) { 
      $scope.message = 'Contact us! JK. This is just a demo.'; 
  });
```

can anyone guide me how do i make ui.router working?

Comment: @Radim can we make this with only one controller that is inside directive?

Comment: Not fully sure here, what you exactly mean, but ... I would say that the solution is really in your code. Because you've used a SERVICE as a data holder. So, anyone can ask for it (IoC) and will get the most recent data. UI-Router controllers are there for managing $scopes of states. So, if you want to render results outside of the directive - we need that data - we need that service. And the state view controller will make it available for its view... Hope it helps (wanted to say, that controllers are closed to views, services play good roles as singletons)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the [updated plunker - WORKING](http://plnkr.co/edit/8VjSkp7ib2HLqSZRQQY8?p=preview)

Your code is almost perfect. The only changes I made - was fixing the wrong names referencing files. Firstly, the root file (ran by Plunker) should be index.html not Code/index.html. Also, states should use templateUrl related to file names, i.e. instead of this:

```
.state('home', { 
    url: '/home', 
    templateUrl: '../templates/home.html', 
    ...
                  }) 
.state('about', { 
    url: '/about', 
    templateUrl: '../templates/about.html', 
    ...
```

we need

```
.state('home', { 
    url: '/home', 
    templateUrl: 'Code/templates/home.html', 
    ...
                  }) 
.state('about', { 
    url: '/about', 
    templateUrl: 'Code/templates/about.html', 
    ...
```

Also, the redirection to be used when wrong url is passed, should target url of some state *(not a template or root html file)*:

```
//$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/index.html'); 
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
```

There were many of these *typos* or *misspellings*. But that's it. The rest is working. Just remember - if we use type **`email`** for registration:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="user.name">
<input type="email" class="form-control" ng-model="user.email">
```

It must be really valid email provided (or in fact some validation logic to disable registering) - to see that result on next screen, e.g.

```
user name:  me
user email: me@my.one
```

Check the [updated version here](http://plnkr.co/edit/8VjSkp7ib2HLqSZRQQY8?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

I can see several things

- when using ui-router, you should use the directive ui-view and not ng-view (which is for ngRoute)
- for the links you should use ui-sref="stateName" instead of href="/", as ui-sref="home"

Comment: i added what you tell but still nothing is displayed

Comment: Ok , if nobody found solution , I will amend the plunker tomorrow! 